# Cannot pass 'var' by 'init' into '@IBAction'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3

I created a pair of xib file with the swift file(for that xib file).
[xib_template.xib & view_template.swift]
And I want to control this pair of xib file by my [main_VC.swift].
xib file have 1 button and 1 label.
I want to change the text of label when I click this button.

I want to set different template view and control them in my [main_VC].
But the @IBAction seems independent inside the class

I pass the value from [main_VC] to [view_template.swift] by init method searched on the internet.
I can get correct value by using func in [main_VC].
But when clicking the button,
the value is always nil.
The var inside IBAction cannot get the value from init.

I am new in swift and I tried my best but still cannot fix this.
How can I get the init value inside IBAction?
Or how can I programmatically create & disable the Ibaction from [main_VC]?

I adjusted my code to be more easy to read.
May have some little typing error.

I searched online and tried all I can already.
One people asked similar question before but have no answer.
Hope for help.
Thanks very much.

[view_template.swift]

```
import UIKit

class View_template_empty: UIView {

    var _uid: String?
    @IBOutlet weak var labellabel: UILabel!

    init (uid: String) {
            self._uid = uid
            super.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    //        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    @IBAction func clickingPanel2(_ sender: Any) {
        print(self._uid)        // always nil !!!!!!
        self.labellabel.text = “test”
    }

    fun test () {
        print(self._uid)        // correct value
    }
}
```

[main_VC] (only copy out the main function)

```
func allocator (_uid: String, uiView: UIView) {
    switch templateType {
        case “one”:
            if let loading_panels = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("xib_template", owner: uiView, options: nil)?.first as? view_template {
                        loading_panels.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
                        uiView.addSubview(loading_panels)

                        loading_panels.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: uiView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
                        loading_panels.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: uiView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
                        loading_panels.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: uiView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
                        loading_panels.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: uiView.topAnchor).isActive = true

            let view_temp = view_template(uid: _uid)
            view_temp.test()
            }
        case “two”:
            if let loading_panels = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("xib_template_two”, owner: uiView, options: nil)?.first as? view_template_two {
                        loading_panels.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
                        uiView.addSubview(loading_panels)

                        loading_panels.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: uiView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
                        loading_panels.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: uiView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
                        loading_panels.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: uiView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
                        loading_panels.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: uiView.topAnchor).isActive = true
            }
        default:
                    print("error")
}
```

Comment: Have you tried printing out the address of `self` in both `test()` and `clickingPanel2 ` functions? Are they the same object? Also you can add a `didSet { print("uid set to \(newValue)") }` to monitor `_uid` in case some other object directly modifies the `_uid`.

Comment: I tested the two ".self", and they are the same. Can you explain more of the "didSet" method? I have no idea how to monitor it. Thanks for your answer

Comment: You can look for examples of `didSet` here https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using different initializers here:

- When you say `let view_temp = view_template(uid: _uid)`, `init (uid: String)` is used and your implementation sets `_uid` so it is not nil.
- When you load a view from a XIB, `init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)` is used and this does not set `_uid` so it is nil.

To inject `_uid` into your templates, simply say `loading_panels._uid = _uid` in your two `if let loading_panels = ...` blocks.

You might also want to read section "[Follow case conventions](https://swift.org/documentation/api-design-guidelines/#follow-case-conventions)" in the Swift API Design Guidelines to brush up on your naming.